# why is the shortcut, sout, not working for me in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've been doing mooc.fi to learn java but because my computer didn't let me install netbeans I used a plug in within intelliJ. For some reason it doesn't respond when I use the shortcut sout but instead puts `SQLOutput`

Answer (score 6):

You can edit the shortcuts in IntelliJ in the settings tab.
Settings/Preferences -> Editor -> Live Templates. Find out the "sout"  shortcut and put "System.out.println();" in the expands to section.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008575319-sout-shortcut

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too. My issue was I was trying to 'sout' outside of the main method, so make sure you're inside the main method first.

Comment: I think you'll find that any place a statement is allowed will work, not just the main method.

Comment: I was trying it directly inside class and it was not working for me. I forgot  to add main method. It doesn't work outside main method. Not sure why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have already figured it out:
you have to type "sout" with all lower case letters. It seems you did it with an uppercase S ( "Sout" )